# c++ No operator found with error c2678

Tags: c++

sorry for the long post, but I have no idea what is causing this, i am teaching myself c++

I tried using only one string variable, and changing it to celsius or fahrenheit if the input is c or f, but it gave the same errors..

**Code:**

```
// Custom.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <String>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

        double input, out;
        string degtype;
        char type ;

        cin >> "What is the temperature: " >> input;
        cin >> "Convert to [C]elsius or [F]ahrenheit?: " >> type;

        if (type=='C' || type=='c')
        {
            out = (-32 - (input * 1.8)) + input;
            degtype = "Celcius";
        }
        else
            if (type=='F' || type=='f')
        {
            out = 32 + (input * 1.8);
            degtype = "Fahrenheit";
        }

            cout << "The " << degtype << "value is " << out;


}
```

**Errors:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Custom, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Custom.cpp
1>c:\users\charles\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\custom\custom\custom.cpp(18): error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1053): could be 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,signed char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1060): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,signed char &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1067): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,unsigned char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1074): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,unsigned char &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1097): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1104): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1111): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1118): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1128): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><char,std::char_traits<char>,const char[26]>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Ty (&))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ty=const char [26]
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(179): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(185): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(192): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(199): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::_Bool &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(218): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(short &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(253): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned short &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(272): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(int &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(298): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned int &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(316): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(long &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(334): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned long &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(354): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(__int64 &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(373): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned __int64 &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(392): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(float &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(411): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(429): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(long double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(447): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(void *&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(466): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::istream, const char [26])'
1>c:\users\charles\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\custom\custom\custom.cpp(19): error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1053): could be 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,signed char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1060): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,signed char &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1067): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,unsigned char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1074): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,unsigned char &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1097): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1104): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1111): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1118): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1128): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><char,std::char_traits<char>,const char[40]>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Ty (&))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ty=const char [40]
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(179): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(185): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(192): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(199): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::_Bool &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(218): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(short &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(253): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned short &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(272): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(int &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(298): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned int &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(316): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(long &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(334): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned long &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(354): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(__int64 &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(373): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned __int64 &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(392): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(float &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(411): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(429): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(long double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(447): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(void *&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(466): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::istream, const char [40])'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2):

The

```
    cin >> "What is the temperature: " >> input;
```

should be

```
    cout << "What is the temperature: ";
    cin >> input;
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the errors caused by  (cin/cout, see answer from NPE):

**Evaluating variable type**

If you enter anything else except F/f/C/c your code will return some gibberish because neither out nor degtype got a value, except the preset one.
You can either solve this by building a recursive function evaluating the output type, predifine a default behaviour which is used in case of an invalid input, handle this case as an error or initialize type as "error".

**Evaluating input recursive:**

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

string evalInput(list<string> acceptedStrings, string textToDisplay)
{
  cout << textToDisplay << endl;
  cin >> input;
  if ( any_of(acceptedStrings.begin(),acceptedStrings.end(),(string)input))
  {
     return input;
  }
  else
  {
     cout<<"Invalid input provided, valid inputs are:" << endl;
     for each (string s in acceptedStrings){ cout << s << endl;}
     evalInput(acceptedStrings,textToDisplay); // calling itself, hence recursive
  }
}
```

**Handle undefined state**

```
if (type=='C' || type=='c')
{
   out = (-32 - (input * 1.8)) + input;
   degtype = "Celcius";
}
else if (type=='F' || type=='f')
{
   out = 32 + (input * 1.8);
   degtype = "Fahrenheit";
}
else
{
   // do whatever you want here, you can inform of a bad input and
   // hence using a default behavior, or simply inform of a bad input 
   // and deny further progress
}
```

**Initialize as error / not initialized**

```
// Preset degtype and out:
degtype = 'E';
out = -999;
```

Now you have to check wether the provided values by degtype and out are errors or not, so you change your last couple lines like this:

```
if (degtype != 'E')
{
   cout << "The " << degtype << "value is " << out;
}
else
{
   cout << "Invalid temprature unit provided, hit any key to terminate program" << endl;
   double terminate;
   cin >> terminate;
}
```

**Evaluating input**

If your user provided any invalid value for input, input won't accept this value, hence I highly recommend preseting this value. After asking your user for the input you can evaluate if the value provided has been valid or not. The easiest way is by preseting input to -999, and checking wether it is still -999 after getting the user input. Since -999 is no valid temperature, it is highly unlikely that any user will ever provide this input.

You can than again either inform of the error, or ask again for the input using a recursive method.

Comment: i just realised this question is three years old :/ poor me writing that much for nothing